# adding pause functionality to google speech to text api

Tags: android-studio, speech-to-text

Hey guys I'm doing a project that requires google speech to text api and I got the code from
 www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/
But I would like to add some funcgiomalities such as pausing it and adding an icon to go to voice settings 
Thanks in advance :)